# getting email from other view controller and store in firebase

Tags: ios, swift5, xcode11

guys, I have email text filed on my previous viewController I want to get value
from another viewController and save to firebase I am using this method but app crashes
error "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" how I can getting value from other view controller and save in firebase

(FIRST viewcontroller)

```
 var getEmail = ""
@IBOutlet weak var email_txt: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    email_txt.text = getEmail

}
```

(SECOND viewcontroller)

```
 @IBAction func sign_up(_ sender: Any) {
    formValidation()

    let storeEmail = EamilView()

    let storeFirebase = storeEmail.email_txt.text!

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: storeFirebase, password: password.text!, completion: { (user: AuthDataResult?, error: Error?)in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
    })


}// button end
```

Comment: is second viewcontroller presented in the view hierarchy before first or not

Comment: yes it's present in the view hierarchy basically I make a signup system on first screen just email and press continue button to go on second screen there is more details like username password and than tap on signup button in order to store data in firebase first get the email from the first screen and other details from the second screen and than tapping the signup button which is a place on the second screen that all

Comment: post the code where you present or push the second VC, also if is a segue or not. just show the selected way to go to the second VC